# Splitting first and last names and then recombining first initial with last name if there are multiple people with the same last name

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-query-language

I have a list of employees of the school. There are several husband/wife pairs that work here, as well as, several people who are unrelated who still share the same last name.

I am trying to prepare the list to print name badges for everyone.

I can use the split function to break apart first and last name, and I have a column that defines the prefix.

What I have so far is:
A2:A923 is first and last names
B2:B923 is first name only
C2:C923 is last name only
D2:D923 is the preferred prefix

Goal:
E2:E923 to be a list of names ready to print on badges.
Examples:
Mrs. J Jones
Ms. D Jones
Mrs. Rackham
Mr. B Hadley
Mrs. A Hadley
Mr. Dunmeyer
etc...

Notice that the first initial is only included when there are more than one individual with the same last name.

I am new to javascript and google app scripts but I have completed a few simple projects. I am pretty good with google functions, but can't figure a way to accomplish this. I've tried IF statements, UNIQUE, SORT and FILTER. I am new to google query language to. I have only used this twice so far, but I think I could manage a query statement if I knew what I was looking for. Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: You should post what you've tried, including a small example of input and expected output. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Couldn't you just use COUNTIF to see if there was more than one person with any particular last name?

Comment: Beautiful, and so simple. I was so focused on trying the more "text" focused functions that I didn't even consider a count function. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom Sharpe suggested:

1. Have a column with a last name only (say, F).
2. Use another column, for example G, to count the number of people with the given last name. E.g., `=countif(F:F, F2)` counts the number of times the content of F2 is in column F.
3. Use a formula with `If` to include first initial only when the value in column G is > 1.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed. I think I was experiencing burn out on the problem. I was so close to it, I needed someone with a little distance to help me with the "oh, duh" moment.